# SwiftUI Double Backslash in Text without Raw Strings

Tags: swiftui

In SwiftUI how can i make Text to show Double Backslashes?
Escaping does not seem to help

```swift
Text("Hello \\\\") // renders to: Hello \
```

Expected Output: `Hello \\`

Raw Strings is not an option here, as localization is not possible without the right escape sequence.

Localization of the String MUST be possible!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is possible variant

```
Text(verbatim: "Hello \\\\")
```

Tested with Xcode 13.3 / iOS 15.4

Comment: While it works, localization with this is NOT possible, as stated in the docs:
"Creates a text view that displays a stored string without localization."

Comment: About localization I answered in your different post